# Cambiemos el nombre de la medalla "Strunk & White" por algo más reconocible

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, traducciones, medallas

### Actualizacion:

La clave generada (9d02413c8af8c1e9c15c87ba689397cb) para esta cadena ya se encuentra en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/filters?key=9d02413c8af8c1e9c15c87ba689397cb)

---

Actualmente tenemos tres medallas para quien edita publicaciones:

- [**Editor**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor) (bronce) → Primera edición.
- [**Strunk & White**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) (plata) → Editar 80 publicaciones.
- [**Editor de textos**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) (oro) →  Editar 500 publicaciones (se excluyen las publicaciones propias o eliminadas y las ediciones de etiqueta).

La de plata debe su nombre a los autores de [*The Elements of Style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style), un libro de estilo del inglés americano escrito por William **Strunk** Jr. y ampliado por E. B. **White**. En Estados Unidos se ve que es un libro de referencia, pero [en el resto de países nos suena poco](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135964/209901).

Dado que Stack Overflow en español está destinado a usuarios hispanohablantes y este libro se refiere al inglés, creo que sería bueno buscar algún equivalente más propio para que tuviera más sentido (de hecho [ya generó confusión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20212/cu%C3%A1l-ser%C3%ADa-la-traducci%C3%B3n-de-strunk-al-espa%C3%B1ol#comment31457_20345)).

Dado que no conozco ningún autor de libro de estilo lo suficientemente relevante y conocido, creo que podríamos optar por usar algún término del tipo [*Manual de estilo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_de_estilo) o *Libro de estilo*.

¿Consideráis apropiado cambiar este nombre? Si es así, ¿qué nombre os parece más convincente?

Comment: Supongo que solo se contaran los votos positivos como en otras "encuestas"

Comment: @jasilva pues no lo sé y la duda me hizo preguntar [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/83).

Comment: Dato: Al momento las dos propuestas que aparentemente lideran están empatadas con una puntuación de 4: Don Quijote +6/-2, Cervantes +4/-0

Comment: Actualice la medalla en traducir. Si alguien tiene una idea mejor, revivamos esto y volvamos a hacer la votacion.

Comment: @gbianchi fíjate que Cervantes tiene +8, mientras que Don Quijote +9/-4. Nunca decidimos cómo determinar ganador, si por puntuación o por votos positivos. Dicho lo cual, qué bueno que se reflotara esto y encontraras la manera de cambiarlo :))

Comment: @fedorqui si queres arrancamos a votar de vuelta, pero esta en traducir.. podemos cambiarlo 1 y 1000 veces :) ya con encontrarlo avanzamos mil kilometros...

Comment: @gbianchi ya está en producción :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sí me parece apropiado cambiar el nombre, propongo:

**Cervantes**

De Miguel de Cervantes por el libro *El Ingenioso Hidalgo de Don Quijote de la Mancha*  queda mejor ya que la medalla original tiene el nombre de los autores

Answer (score 7):

Sí me parece apropiado cambiar el nombre, propongo:

**Don Quijote**

Simplemente porque es uno de los libros mas famosos del español.

<sub>Aparte como medalla se escucha bastante bien ;)</sub>

Comment: ¡Me gusta! Qué más quijotesco que enfrentarse a esos molinos gigantes que son las publicaciones que necesitan ser editadas :D

Answer (score 3):

Sí me parece apropiado cambiar el nombre, propongo:

**100 años de ediciones**

Por la obra [Cien años de soledad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cien_a%C3%B1os_de_soledad) de [Gabriel García Márquez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Garc%C3%ADa_M%C3%A1rquez). Bastante reconocida y considerada una obra maestra de la literatura hispanoamericana y universal.

Comment: ¿Y si la de oro la cambiamos a **100 años editando** ? :)

Comment: @jasilva me parece perfecto :D o también 100 años de ediciones :P

Answer (score 1):

Propongo lo siguiente:

- **Editor** (bronce - una publicación)
- **Editor persistente** (plata - 80 publicaciones)
- **Editor imbatible** (oro - 500 publicaciones)

Answer (score -1):

Sí me parece apropiado cambiar el nombre, propongo:

**Covarrubias**

Por [Sebastián de Covarrubias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebasti%C3%A1n_de_Covarrubias), autor en 1611 del primer diccionario del español: [*Tesoro de la lengua castellana*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesoro_de_la_lengua_castellana_o_espa%C3%B1ola). Esta obra pone el foco en la etimología, es decir el origen de las palabras. Por ello, creo que es pertinente sugerirlo pues representa a todo aquel que quiere ir al fondo de la cuestión, aportando claridad e indagando en el origen de las palabras/los problemas para conseguir llegar a su solución. Lo que hacemos aquí cuando editamos, vaya :)

Comment: Me gustó esta pero para la medalla de Oro.

Answer (score -4):

No me parece cambiar el nombre, deja las cosas como están.

Comment: Oh, como siempre atento Rubén. Muchas gracias por formalizar la votación mostrando las opciones tanto de acuerdo como de desacuerdo.