# ¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?

Tags: discusión, meta

Ayer publiqué [Cambiemos el nombre de la medalla “Strunk & White” por algo más reconocible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2077/83). Es una propuesta que generó respuestas interesantes en las que no solo aceptaban mi argumento sino que sugerían nuevos nombres. Me gustó mucho verlo :)

Después me quedé pensando: ¿Cómo gestionamos estas preguntas-encuestas? ¿No os parece que deberíamos definir unas líneas maestras sobre la metodología para que no queden en el limbo?

Se me ocurre por ejemplo que:

- Cuando una propuesta sea importante, que los moderadores la destaquen durante ¿una semana?, al término de la cual se cierre la votación.
- Si una sugerencia tiene una puntuación de al menos ¿10? (sumando votos positivos y restando los negativos), se la tenga en cuenta.
- Si hay distintas respuestas, que se considere "ganadora popular" a aquella que tenga una mayor puntuación (sumando votos positivos y restando los negativos), que esta sea de al menos ¿5? y lo haga con cierta diferencia respecto las otras.

Pero aún así siempre es difícil determinar si solamente debemos tener en cuenta los votos a favor de algo o si -prefiero yo- se tiene en cuenta el balance final entre positivos y negativos. Por ejemplo, no es lo mismo tener una propuesta respaldada por 5 personas que una respaldada por 8 y rechazada por 3 -la primera muestra unanimidad, mientras que la segunda muestra una cierta confrontación que no puede ser obviada.

¿Cómo deberíamos operar? ¿A partir de qué punto los moderadores deben dar por bueno un resultado? ¿Definimos un plazo estándar de duración de la encuesta?

Así que... ¿hacemos una votación al respecto? :P

<sub>Me refiero, claro está, a esas preguntas que se puedan gestionar internamente: definición de etiquetas, solicitudes de quemado, unión de etiquetas, motivos de cierre de preguntas... El resto que requieren de empleados de Stack Exchange no sé cómo se gestionan ([y parece que nadie lo sabe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263662/209901)) y no sé cuáles son las cosas que [JuanM](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) puede empujar ni si nuestro sitio tiene alguna prioridad especial (ejemplo: `s.tk/soes` [se materializó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1801/83) en apenas unos días, mientras que lo pedí en otro sitio y nunca más se supo de ello).</sub>

Comment: El problema es que si voto a favor de lo que quiero, y le tiro -1 a todo lo demás, ¿no sería lo mismo?

Comment: Me cuesta un poco racionalizar esta pregunta. Estás asumiendo que se puede definir un umbral para que "***se la tenga en cuenta***", pero asumiendo que podamos definir una metodología con la que todos acuerden, ¿hay algo que garantice que se la va a tener en cuenta? La verdad es que nadie le dicta la agenda a un moderador/CM/dev, por lo que definir esa parte me suena un poco utópico... Ojalá esté equivocado, pero ¿qué sentido tiene preguntar por una puntuación base?... Además, si se fijara un umbral, ¿serían lo mismo x votos en algo de [tag:java] que x votos en [tag:cobol]?

Comment: @Mariano sí, soy consciente de que es un tema genérico y difícil de conseguir consenso porque atañe a distintas casuísticas. Me daría por satisfecho si lográramos aunque sea un compromiso de que en todo aquello _automáticamente realizable_ (por moderadores, por ejemplo), se consensúe que a partir de X días de abierto y con un mínimo de Y votos a favor se le asigne un [meta-tag:estado-planeado] y que se acabe haciendo. Ahora mismo la no respuesta y la sensación de que las cosas quedan en el aire es algo desalentadora. En cuanto a cosas de CM, ignoro cuáles son sus atribuciones reales.

Comment: @fedorqui te imaginarás cuánto me encantaría que se vayan realizando los pendientes que tenemos ignorados!!!!!! Es nomás que yo me trabo si intento pensarlo así, pero obviamente sería genial si se consigue algo desde esta publicación.

Comment: Relacionado: [Comentarios e iniciativas en sitios internacionales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3658/65)

Answer (score 6):

Una propuesta bastante interesante sin duda.

Para este caso, veo dos tipos de encuestas que pueden existir.

- Encuestas cerradas. Pregunta directa, opciones fijas (no más, no menos):

  - [Unamos las etiquetas “threads” e “hilos”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271/unamos-las-etiquetas-threads-e-hilos)
- Encuestas abiertas. Si la opción no existe, agregar el elemento:

  - [Celebración para la graduación del sitio en México](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1843/celebraci%C3%B3n-para-la-graduaci%C3%B3n-del-sitio-en-m%C3%A9xico)
  - [Cambiemos el nombre de la medalla “Strunk & White” por algo más reconocible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2077/cambiemos-el-nombre-de-la-medalla-strunk-white-por-algo-m%C3%A1s-reconocible)

Una especie de suposición que se ha segido (por lo menos en los dos primeros ejemplos) es que [en la votación solo contarán los votos positivos, como en otras encuestas que hemos tenido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1843/celebraci%C3%B3n-para-la-graduaci%C3%B3n-del-sitio-en-m%C3%A9xico#comment5391_1843) (gracias a [jasilva](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2027/jasilva) por ese gran comentario).

Aunque de igual forma deja lugar a discusiones, por ejemplo:

- Votación de la pregunta **A**:

  - Respuesta X: `+15/-20`
  - Respuesta Y:  `+12/0`
  - Respuesta Z: `+10/-10`

Donde se podrían dar `N` números de combinaciones posibles pero solo se mantiene una regla, los votos positivos son los que cuentan.

En mi opinión personal, esta sería una manera más sana de realizar algún tipo de votación en caso que esta se llegase a dar.

Comment: Lo de sólo contar los votos positivos no es una suposición, sino una forma eficiente de que el voto de cada usuario sólo valga 1... En caso contrario, si votara +1 en A y -1 en B, estaría generando una diferencia de 2. Además, así evitamos que se esté llenando de negativos a las respuestas.

Comment: No entendí qué quisiste decir con que "*deja lugar a discusiones*"

Comment: @Mariano edité mi respuesta para ejemplificar un caso donde se pueda dar una discusión. En este caso, ganaría la respuesta X por tener más votos a favor, sin embargo, también es la que tiene más en contra, no obstante, la respuesta Y tiene 12 a favor y cero en contra. Se podría dar una discusión ya que a pesar que la repuesta X es la más votada, también es la más votos en contra tiene. Aunque siguiendo la regla, la que tiene más votos gana, sin importar que también sea la respuesta más odiada.

Comment: ah. Ahora entendí a qué te referías. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en aclararlo. Sí, sólo contar los positivos ayuda a evitar problemas, es un voto por persona.

Comment: Gracias Flxtr por intentar ponerle orden a todo esto :) Se me ocurre que se podría realizar algún tipo de segunda ronda con las dos mejores opciones si hay demasiada controversia en cuanto a las opciones.

Answer (score 4):

En [Make it easier to prevent new questions being added in a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/1983854), Shog9 (Community Manager de Stack Overflow) explica el proceso que siguen para realizar una solicitud de quemado.

Básicamente consiste en (traducción muy libre y destacando lo que nos importa):

1. Cuando una pregunta del tipo [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) se publica, se marca como [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) hasta que llega a una reputación de 20.
2. Entonces se le añade la etiqueta [destacado](/questions/tagged/destacado) durante un día, para que la vea cuanta más gente mejor y así todos opinen al respecto.
3. Pasado ese día de exposición prominente, un moderador o un miembro del Community Team revisan si la solicitud cumple con los criterios definidos (en su caso [There are four criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)). Si alguno de los requisitos no se cumple, se deja caer la iniciativa.
4. Si la etiqueta se elimina fácilmente, se va al paso #6. Si necesita algo de trabajo, se le añade la etiqueta [status-planeado](/questions/tagged/status-planeado) para indicar que se está trabajando en ello.
5. Cuando el paso #4 se ha completado, el encargado de validar que todo está bien lanza un reporte para que un moderador proceda con el paso #6.
6. Se eliminan todas las preguntas cerradas y con puntaje negativo que tienen esta etiqueta.

---

Me gusta mucho esta manera de proceder porque:

- Define un límite a partir del cual los moderadores o CM deben prestar atención a algo.
- Da opción de que todo el mundo se entere, incluso los no presentes en Meta, y den su opinión durante una ventana de tiempo definida.
- Incluye un proceso posterior de validación manual para que no se "cuele" cualquier cosa.

Hecho en falta una regla clara sobre cuántos votos son necesarios para proceder tras destacarlo, eso sí. Y tampoco se habla de ello en el subsiguiente [Evaluation of SOCVR's Burnination Process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323121/1983854).

Tomando como referente la [muy provechosa respuesta de Flxtr](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2137/83), yo optaría por contar solamente votos positivos pero si dos opciones quedan muy parejas, con bastante voto negativo, realizar una "fase final".

Además, apostaría crear algún tipo de baremo entre el número de preguntas y dar más peso a los usuarios que frecuentan la etiqueta. Así, a vuelapluma se me ocurre algo así como:

- si tienes medalla de oro: el voto vale *5
- si tienes medalla de plata: voto vale *3
- si tienes medalla de bronce: voto vale *2

(sería más lógico 10-4-1 pero me parece muy descompensado)

Y que el número de votos fuera del tipo:

- tantos votos positivos como un tercio de los usuarios con puntaje mayor de 100 en la etiqueta.

También haría falta que CM y moderadores definieran qué cosas se pueden plantear. Mi lista rápida incluiría:

- nombre de etiquetas
- unión de etiquetas (sinónimos, decidiendo también cuál es el principal)
- ¿nombre de medallas? creo que esta sería bonita