# ¿Sinónimo [archivo] ← [file], o archivamos el tema?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Creo que deberíamos hacer el sinónimo:
[archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archivo) ← [file](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file)

Lo [propuse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/archivo/synonyms) hace un tiempo, pero [Álvaro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) me planteó un punto que vale la pena discutir: [file](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) puede referirse al tipo de dato.

Creo que cuando nos referimos a un tipo de dato, sería una meta-etiqueta que no vale la pena mantener. En cambio, cuando se refiere al manejo de archivos, si bien no se sostiene como una etiqueta individual me parece que es muy útil en las búsquedas.

¿Qué les parece? ¿Va como sinónimo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En mi opinión,si. No veo sentido a tener [file](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) como etiqueta refiriéndose a un tipo de dato.

Comment: Cuantos upvotes para hacer efectivo el cambio?

Comment: @lois6b yo lo dejaría unos dias o una semana y ya. Tampoco creo que vaya a recibir mucha atención esta pregunta :)

Comment: @lois6b probablemente sea el momento de que los moderadores defináis algún método para estas cosas. Juan M planteó [¿Cuál es el proceso de remover etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/83) y también yo escribí [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/83)

Comment: @fedorqui totalmente de acuerdo. Muchas propuestas terminan en el limbo

Comment: E incluiría, luego de la definición que está planteando fedorqui (que es más que necesaria), revisar las publicaciones que están pendientes, o marcar como [meta-tag:estado-completado] las que ya se hicieron... Creo que en el tema de sinónimos quedamos bastante bien después del día de furia de ArtEze, aprovecharía para terminar de emprolijar a Meta.

Comment: @lois6b creo que también pasa por un poco de sentido común. Esta etiqueta no creo que le importe a nadie... Vamos, yo la sugerí hace mucho pero ni me molesté en publicar en Meta hasta el comentario de Álvaro... Acuerdo con lo que dijo Pikoh. Es sólo una cuestión de dar lugar para ver si alguien se opone... Y esto puede ser un punto más a agregar en la definición del método ("*si el sinónimo se cae de maduro usando el sentido común...*").

Comment: @lois6b : ¿Ya viste [¿Cuáles son los pasos a seguir en la creación de un sinónimo de etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3064/65)?

Comment: @Rubén no habia visto tu respuesta. Ahora cuando pueda la leo. Gracias por hacermelo llegar

Comment: Ya se creó el sinónimo